# "I get utf-8 error when django makemessages command runs"

Tags: python, django, makemessages

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessages.py", line 430, in handle
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessages.py", line 508, in build_potfiles
    self.process_files(file_list)
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessages.py", line 599, in process_files
    self.process_locale_dir(locale_dir, files)
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemessages.py", line 675, in process_locale_dir
    msgs, errors, status = popen_wrapper(args)
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "myvenv\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\utils.py", line 26, in popen_wrapper
    p.stdout.decode(stdout_encoding),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfe in position 978: invalid start byte
```

When I run the "django makemessages" command, I keep getting this error. I've gone through all the files in a loop to check for UTF-8 issues, but I couldn't find any. I've verified that all my files are encoded in UTF-8, but I still keep encountering this error.

Comment: Are you dealing with any file upload process ?

Comment: No, I want to create a language file with the makemessages command. After running the "manage.py makemessages -l en" command it gives this error

Comment: It sometimes happens when you copy the contents of original file into new and load that new file.